# PAT is not working with Git Version 2.7.4

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

This article - https://seb-nyberg.medium.com/accessing-git-repositories-on-azure-devops-using-personal-access-tokens-on-linux-7fa7495bf1e is working for git version - 2.17.1 but not for 2.7.4

On 2.7.4 it does not consider the credentials passed over header and keeps prompting for username and password.

Is PAT not supported for git version 2.7.4 ?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can try to downgraded curl from 7.61 to 7.60.

Here is a [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/git-can-no-longer-authenticate-with-vsts-personal/304030) with the same issue, you can refer to it for details.

Comment: Already I was using curl version 7.47.0. I have also tried upgrading to curl version 7.77.0 but still no luck.

When I upgraded the git version from 2.7.4 to 2.17.1 on the same ubuntu machine it worked.

Wanted to know if this is an issue with the git version, which could not pass the headers to Azure Devops ?